# Adding to each element of a Flux a List attribute obtained from a MongoDB reactive query

Tags: mongodb, mono, flux, reactive

First time posting, I am learning reactive streams in Spring and I got the following problem.

I have a mongo repository for the class Workspace and another repository for the class Model.

When I query for all the workspaces, I get a Flux and I would like for each of the elements in this flux to be converted to a new class called WorkspaceDTO and make a query to the modelsRepository to retrieve all the models which attribute workspaceName is equal to my workspace name, adding this result to an attribute of WorkspaceDTO which is a List

I have been trying some things but haven't figured a way of doing this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to do it with this code:

```
 Flux<Workspace> workspaces = repository.findAll();

        return workspaces
                .map(ws -> {
                    Mono<List<Model>> workspaceModels = modelRepository.findByWorkspaceName(ws.getName()).collectList();
                    return Mono.zip(Mono.just(ws),workspaceModels)
                            .map(t -> new WorkspaceDTO(t.getT1(),t.getT2()));

                })
                .flatMap(Flux::concat) //This operation transform a Flux<Mono<WorkspaceDTO>> into Flux<WorkspaceDTO>
                .log();
```